# jQuery updating rails form partial based on selected item in drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my rails app I have a dropdown menu that a user can select an account to make a payment to:

```
    //_payment.html.erb

     <div class="field" id="payment-to-account">
      <%= f.label 'Payment To:' %><br>
      <%= f.collection_select :to_account_id, @liability_account_payment_list, :id, :account_details, {include_blank: 'Please Select'} %>
    </div>
```

When the user selects a account I render a partial inside of this form based on their selection:

```
    //_payment.html.erb
    <%= form_for(@transaction, 
             as: :transaction,
             url: 
             @transaction.id ? account_transaction_path(@account, @transaction) : account_transactions_path) do |f| %>

    ...

    <% @f = f %>
    <div id="to-account-form" style="display:none;"></div>

    ...
    <script>

    jQuery(function(){

      $("#payment-to-account").change(function() {
        var selected_item = $( "#payment-to-account option:selected" ).text();
        var selected_item_index = $( "#payment-to-account option:selected" ).index(); 
        //looks for account type in parentheses followed by space moneysign " $"
        var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)\s\$/;
        var matches = regExp.exec(selected_item);

    // array of account ids in order of list
    var payment_account_ids = <%= raw @payment_list_ids %>;

    switch (matches[1]) {
      case 'Mortgage':
        $('#to-account-form').html("<%= j render 'payment_to_mortgage', f: @f %>");
        $('#to-account-form').slideDown(350);
        break;
      case 'PersonalLoan':
      case 'CreditCard':
      case 'StudentLoan':
      case 'OtherLiability':
        $('#to-account-form').html("<%= j render 'payment_to_all_other_liabilities', f: @f %>");
        $('#to-account-form').slideDown(350);
        break;
      default:
        $('#to-account-form').html("<br>" + "Contact support, an error has occurred");
        $('#to-account-form').slideDown(350);
        }
      });

    });

    </script>
```

Right now it renders the correct partial based on the selection, but when that partial loads I need more information from the account model. I created a method called find_pay_to_account that take the input selected account id in the Accounts model that looks for the account based on the id.

When the user selects and account from the drop down, I'd like that method called on the partial that is loaded so I can show the user additional information about the account they are making a payment to before they submit the form. But I don't know how. I wanted to add something like this to my jQuery switch statement.

```
    selected_account_id = payment_account_ids[selected_item_index-1]
    @payment_to_account = Account.find_pay_to_account(selected_account_id)
```

Since rails preloads the partials in the background, making the following change to my partial render in the case statements still wont work:

From this

```
  $('#to-account-form').html("<%= j render 'payment_to_mortgage', f: @f %>");
```

To this

```
  $('#to-account-form').html("<%= j render 'payment_to_mortgage', f: @f, @payment_to_account: @payment_to_account %>");
```

I did some searching and found that with AJAX might be able to help:
    [Pragmatic Studio](https://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2015/3/18/rails-jquery-ajax)
    [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised)

But i'm trying to access the model, not the controller and I'm trying to update a form partial. What is the correct way to do this?

Here are pics that show the user flow. An example of what I'm trying to update can be seen in the last pic. When the mortgage account is selected, it needs to show the minimum payment for the mortgage account. Right now it says zero because the partials rendering with all the information from BOA seed 0214.

[image: Step1]

[image: Step2]

[image: Step3]

[image: Step4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the information in the rendered partial without making another controller action, I collected all data I might need in the original action. That way I could get the exact result I was looking for without changing my routes and doing ajax request.

To do this I added methods to the controller new action. You can see from my original question, all accounts I may need information for are in the variable that is in the dropdown menu:

```
@liability_account_payment_list
```

This is where the dropdown menu gets its information from

[image]

That variable is in the Transaction controller new action. So I created another variable storing an array on the line after the above variable:

```
@liability_accounts_payment_list_minimum_payments = @liability_account_payment_list.map {|account| account.minimum_payment.to_f + account.minimum_escrow_payment.to_f}
```

This new variable is an array of all the accounts minimum payments in the order they are listed in the dropdown menu the user will select from.

Then I changed the jQuery on the page to the following

```
//_payments.html.erb
<script>

jQuery(function(){

  $("#payment-to-account").change(function() {
    var selected_item = $( "#payment-to-account option:selected" ).text();
    var selected_item_index = $( "#payment-to-account option:selected" ).index(); 
    //looks for something in parentheses followed by space moneysign " $"
    var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)\s\$/;
    var matches = regExp.exec(selected_item);

    // array of minimum payments from accounts in list converted from ruby to js
    var min_payments = <%= raw @liability_accounts_payment_list_minimum_payments %>;
    // set the js variable to the appropriate minimum payment
    var selected_account_min_payment = min_payments[selected_item_index-1];

    switch (matches[1]) {
      case 'Mortgage':
        $('#to-account-form').html("<%= j render 'payment_to_mortgage', f: @f %>");

        $("#min-payment-field-hidden").val(selected_account_min_payment);
        $("#min-payment-field").html(selected_account_min_payment);

        $('#to-account-form').slideDown(350);
        break;
      case 'PersonalLoan':
      case 'CreditCard':
      case 'StudentLoan':
      case 'OtherLiability':
        $('#to-account-form').html("<%= j render 'payment_to_all_other_liabilities', f: @f %>");

        $("#min-payment-field-hidden").val(selected_account_min_payment);
        $("#min-payment-field").html(selected_account_min_payment);

        $('#to-account-form').slideDown(350);
        break;
      default:
        $('#to-account-form').html("<br>" + "Contact support, an error has occurred");
        $('#to-account-form').slideDown(350);
    }
  });

});

</script>
```

The lines that have min-payment-field-hidden are because setting two different divs with the same id does not work. One div is being used to set hidden_field, the other is showing the user what the value is.

```
//_payment.html.erb
<-- To make sure the appropriate minimum payment is submitted to controller -->
<%= f.hidden_field :amount, :id => "min-payment-field-hidden" %>

<div>
  <%= f.label "Minimum Payment" %>
  <div id="min-payment-field"></div>
</div>
```

If you look at my switch statement, you can see I set the above value with these lines:

```
$("#min-payment-field-hidden").val(selected_account_min_payment);
$("#min-payment-field").html(selected_account_min_payment);
```

Now the user can see the minimum payment for the specific account they choose from the dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access record information from your model inside of front-end javascript you will indeed want to setup a small api to query the database for that information. In ajax it would be something like this

```
function processDataFunction(data){
  console.log(data)
}

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/some-path/:some_id",
  success: processDataFunction(data){}
});



#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/some-path/:some_id", to: "some_controller#some_view", :defaults => { :format => :json }
end

#app/controllers/some_controller.rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_view
    @some_records = SomeModel.find_by_id(params[:some_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @some_records }
    end
  end
end
```